# if statement in an array - given cart meta & variation id | Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

What is the best practice to set up an if statement in an array with multiple statements?

### if `'variant_id'` is `null` use `'external_variant_id'`

Something like this image below, or any other insight would be helpful.

[image]

Example where there is a conflict between `'variant_id'` & `'external_variant_id'`

```
  $valued = get_post_meta( $item['data']->get_id(), 'printful_variant_id', true),

  $request['items'] [] = array(

  'variant_id'=> $valued,

  'external_variant_id' => $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'],
```

**Update** Full use example from Barmar's answer

```
    foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item ) {

    $valued = get_post_meta( $item['data']->get_id(), 'printful_variant_id', true);

    if ($valued) {
        $request['items'] [] = array(
             'variant_id'=> $valued,
            'quantity'            => $item['quantity'],
            'value'               => $item['line_total'] / $item['quantity'],
        );
    }else {
            $request['items'] [] = array(
     'external_variant_id' => $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'],

            'quantity'            => $item['quantity'],
            'value'               => $item['line_total'] / $item['quantity'],
     );
    }
   }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you need the `$valued` variable, just do `'variant_id' => get_post_meta(...)`

Comment: If you need the variable, assign it before the assignment to `$request['items'][]`

Comment: `$valued = ...; $request['items'][] = array('variant_id' => $valued, ...)`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, yes that's cleaner I edited the question. Problem is  `external_variant_id` takes precedence when both `external_variant_id` and  `variant_id` are used. I'm looking for a way to make `varient_id` take priority and if the value is returned as null then use the `external_varient_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the array separately with all the common keys, and use conditional assignments for the parts that differ.

```
$item = array('quantity'            => $item['quantity'],
              'value'               => $item['line_total'] / $item['quantity'],
);
$valued = get_post_meta( $item['data']->get_id(), 'printful_variant_id', true);
if ($valued) {
    $item['variant_id'] = $valued;
} elseif ($item['variation_id']) {
    $item['external_variant_id'] = $item['variation_id'];
else {
    $item['external_variant_id'] = $item['product_id'];
}
$request['items'][] = $item;
```

There's no prize for squeezing it all into the array assignment. But you can use the  enhanced ternary operator to simplify the last expression.

```
if ($valued) {
    $item['variant_id'] = $valued;
} else {
    $item['external_variant_id'] = $item['variation_id'] ?: $item['product_id'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great! Modified it slightly for my use and added the full example to the end of the original question. Cheers!

Comment: If there are parts of the array that are the same in both cases, I recommend putting them in the `$item` assignment at the beginning, so you don't have to duplicate the code. Try to obey the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.